# Joystick adapter from 9-pin to USB

Tags: commodore-64, amiga, joystick

I have still a couple of old C64/Amiga joysticks and I'd like to use them on  [the New C64](https://retrogames.biz/thec64), which has USB ports.

Is there an adapter from 9-pin male to USB?

[This 3-year old article](https://www.breadbox64.com/blog/usb-joystick-adapters/) references a company called Despegatop making such adapters, but it looks like they've stopped since.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how the New C64 implements USB HID, so I can't guarantee compatibility, but here are the options I'm aware of:

- [Stepstick.pl](https://stepstick.pl/?35,en_usbjoy20-adapter-connect-your-atari-amiga-c64-joystick-to-pc!-develop-your-own-usb-device!) appears to still be selling C64-to-USB adapters if you want something pre-assembled. (They sell two products, but I couldn't figure out how to set the "English, please" cookie without linking to a specific product)
- [Commodore4ever](https://commodore4ever.net/collections/commodore-computers-and-parts/products/retro-usb-joystick-to-usb-adapter) is also selling an adapter that they also offer via an eBay listing as I'm writing this.

If you need something that appears as a USB keyboard and you're handy with microcontrollers, here are some options:

- A [5-minute project](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/fpfaffendorf/commodore-64-joystick-usb-adapter-c64joy-fc2389) using an Arduino Leonardo.
- Frank Buß's [project](https://frank-buss.de/joystickadapter/) using a Freescale microcontroller.

I'm not sure what kind of HID device it presents as, but Markus Gritsch also did [a design](http://dangerousprototypes.com/forum/index.php?topic=2971.0) using a PIC microcontroller.

Comment: I've bought the adapter from Stepstick.pl, seems to work well.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few options still readily available; one is [the 2600-daptor](http://2600-daptor.com/), which supports many 9-pin devices (not just 2600 joysticks and paddles). Another, more expensive, one is [the Bliss Box](https://bliss-box.net/) which supports many different controllers and connectors (with adapter cables).

You can also build your own, using for example [the Stelladaptor schematics and BOM](http://www.grandideastudio.com/stelladaptor-2600/).

All these devices are USB HID controllers, and are thus compatible with most USB-equipped systems.